# Confusion on how to calculate mean value

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics, intuition

I've done this type of thing in multiple classes over multiple years since high school, and still, when it's presented to me, I fumble around like a dope.

> Consider a gas of $N_0$ non-interacting molecules enclosed in
>   a container of volume $V_0$. Focus attention on any sub-volume, $V$, of this
>   container and denote by $N$ the number of molecules located within this
>   sub-volume. Each molecule is equally likely to be located anywhere within
>   the container; hence the probability that a given molecule is located within
>   the sub-volume $V$ is simply equal to $\frac{V}{V_0}$.
>
> (a) What is the mean number, $\bar{N}$, of molecules located within $V$? Express
>   your answer in terms of $N_0$, $V_0$, and $V$.

So, the probability of a given molecule being in $V$ is just $\frac{V}{V_0}$. These molecules are independent of one another; thus, the probability of two given molecules being in $V$ should be $\left( \frac{V}{V_0} \right)^2$, the probability of three given molecules in $V$ should be $\left( \frac{V}{V_0} \right)^3$, etc. ... right?

The expected value of $N$ should be the sum of each outcome's probability multiplied by the outcome: $\bar{N} = \sum_{N = 1}^{N_0} \left( \frac{V}{V_0} \right)^NN$.

But this doesn't make sense; it should be the case that $\bar{N} \rightarrow N_0$ as $V \rightarrow V_0$. Clearly that does not happen in the above summation. I think, "Well, the probability is for a *given* particle. There are many ways that $V$ could have, say, 3 particles—there must be some issue with including duplicates."

So, I divide each term in the summation by $N!$, since there are $N!$ ways of creating a particular result. $\bar{N} = \sum_{N = 1}^{N_0} \left( \frac{V}{V_0} \right)^N \frac{1}{(N-1)!}$. This is *definitely* not right.

Aside from all the different little things I've tweaked, by far, the **biggest** problem is that *all* of these things *make complete and total sense to me*. There's a very fundamental intuition that I have that's both inconsistent with other "intuitions" on the same thing, and very wrong.

Could someone offer some help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of the problem this way:  each particle is a "trial" and the outcome of that trial is "success" if we find that particle inside the volume $V$.  The probability of any given trial (particle) being found inside $V$ is $p = V/V_0$.  Because the particles do not interact and are indistinguishable, then these trials are independent and identically distributed.  So the number of successes $X$ in $n = N_0$ trials is a binomially distributed random variable with probability of success $p$, and the expected number of such successes is simply $\operatorname{E}[X] = np = N_0 V/V_0$.

This analogy also gives us the exact probability distribution for the number of particles found in $V$:  it is $$\Pr[X = x] = \binom{N_0}{x} \left(\frac{V}{V_0}\right)^x \left(1 - \frac{V}{V_0}\right)^{N_0 - x}, \quad x = 0, 1, 2, \ldots, N_0.$$

We can prove that the expectation is $np$ by seeing that a binomial random variable is the sum of $n$ independent and identically distributed Bernoulli trials.  That is to say, if particle $i$ (where $i \in \{1, 2, \ldots, N_0\}$) is found in the volume $V$, then $X_i = 1$ with probability $p = V/V_0$, otherwise $X_i = 0$.  Then the expected value of $X_i$ is just $\operatorname{E}[X_i] = \Pr[X_i = 1] = p$, and the sum of $N_0$ such Bernoulli variables is $N_0 p = N_0 V/V_0$, as claimed.

Answer (score 1):

The probability of ONLY two molecules being in the volume is
$p^2(1-p)^{N-2}$ times the combinatorial (n, 2). Where $p$ is V/V0.
Etc Etc

Answer (score 1):

Lets say we partition the container into several volumes: $V_i$ (i.e., $\sum V_i=V_0$)

At any time, we know that the number of molecules in each volume is some random number $N_i$, but $\sum N_i = N_0$

However, each molecule can be anywhere, therefore, this box will have uniform density $\delta$. This implies that $N_i\propto V_i$ or $N_i = kV_i$

Substituting this into the particle count constriant we get:

$$\sum kV_i=kV_0=N_0 \implies k=\frac{N_0}{V_0}$$

By linearity of expectation:

$$E\left[\sum \frac{N_0V_i}{V_0}\right]=\sum E\left[\frac{N_0V_i}{V_0}\right]=N_0 \implies E[N_i]=\frac{N_0V_i}{V_0} $$

Statistically speaking:

You can associate a bernoulli random variable with each particle: $B_i\sim Ber\left(\frac{V}{V_0}\right)$ Thus the number of particles in your box will have a binomial distribution:

$$N_i\sim Bin\left(N_0,\frac{V_i}{V_0}\right)$$

The expected value of a binomial distribution $Bin(n,p)$ is $np$. In your case:

$$E[N_i]=\frac{N_0V_i}{V_0}$$